# Using Entity Manager to return a List, but instead It returns a list inside a list. why?

Tags: java, entitymanager

This is my method:

```java
@Override
public List<Quota> getAllQuota(Pageable pageable, QuotaRequestFiltered qreq) {
    String baseQuery = "FROM Quota q, QuotaLine ql, Deal d " + "where ql.quota = q " + "and ql.deal = d ";

    String queryState = "";

    if (qreq.getState() != 0) {
        queryState = " and q.state.id = " + qreq.getState();
    }

    String queryClient = "";

    if (qreq.getClient() != 0) {
        queryClient = " and ql.client.id = " + qreq.getClient();
    }

    String queryDealNumber = "";

    if (qreq.getDeal_number() != null) {
        queryDealNumber = " and d.dealNumber = '" + qreq.getDeal_number() + "'";
    }

    String queryDateRequest = "";

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    if (qreq.getDate_request_from() != null && qreq.getDate_request_to() != null) {
        String dateFrom = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_request_from());
        String dateTo = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_request_to());
        queryDateRequest = " and q.dateRequest between to_timestamp('" + dateFrom + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")and to_timestamp('" + dateTo + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    } else if (qreq.getDate_request_from() != null) {
        String dateFrom = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_request_from());
        queryDateRequest = " and q.dateRequest >= to_timestamp('" + dateFrom + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    } else if (qreq.getDate_request_to() != null) {
        String dateTo = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_request_to());
        queryDateRequest = " and q.dateRequest <= to_timestamp('" + dateTo + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    }

    String queryDateWithdraw = "";

    if (qreq.getDate_withdraw_from() != null && qreq.getDate_withdraw_to() != null) {
        String dateFrom = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_withdraw_from());
        String dateTo = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_withdraw_to());
        queryDateWithdraw = " and q.dateWithdraw between to_timestamp('" + dateFrom + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")and to_timestamp('" + dateTo + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    } else if (qreq.getDate_withdraw_from() != null) {
        String dateFrom = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_withdraw_from());
        queryDateWithdraw = " and q.dateWithdraw >= to_timestamp('" + dateFrom + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    } else if (qreq.getDate_withdraw_to() != null) {
        String dateTo = dateFormat.format(qreq.getDate_withdraw_to());
        queryDateWithdraw = " and q.dateWithdraw <= to_timestamp('" + dateTo + "','DD-MM-YYYYHH24MISS'" + ")";
    }

    String finalQuery = baseQuery + queryState + queryClient + queryDealNumber + queryDateRequest + queryDateWithdraw;

    Query query = em.createQuery(finalQuery); /// em -> @PersistanceContext
                                                /// private EntityManager em;
    List<Quota> quotas = query.getResultList();

    return quotas;

}
```

Quota:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "quotas")
public class Quota extends FullBaseEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "quota_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "quota_seq", 
                       name = "quota_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private State state;
                    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name="date_request")
    private LocalDateTime dateRequest;

    @Column(name="date_withdraw")
    private LocalDateTime dateWithdraw;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cargo_depot_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private CargoDepot cargoDepot;
    
    @Column(name="name_carrier", length=255)
    private String nameCarrier;

    @Column(name="phone_carrier", length=100)
    private String phoneCarrier;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "transport_id", referencedColumnName ="id")
    private Transport transport;
    
    @NotNull
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_type_carrier_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private DocType docTypeCarrier;
    
    @Column(name="document_carrier", length=100)
    private String documentCarrier;

    @Column(name="patent_chassis", length=100)
    private String patentChassis;
    
    @Column(name="coupled_patent", length=100)
    private String coupledPatent;
    
    @Column(name="comment", length=100)
    private String comment;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "rejectionReason", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private RejectReason rejectionReason;
    
    
//  @Cascade({ CascadeType.,CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
//  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quota",cascade = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
//  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "quota", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
//  private List<QuotaLine> lines  = new ArrayList<>();
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "quota")
//  @JoinColumn(name = "quota_id")
    private List<QuotaLine> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

QuotaLine:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "quota_lines")
public class QuotaLine extends FullBaseEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "quota_lines_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "quota_lines_seq", 
                       name = "quota_lines_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "quota_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Quota quota;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Client client;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Product product;
    
//  @OneToOne
//    @JoinColumn(name = "weight_unit_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
//  private WeightUnit weightUnit;
    
    @Column(name="ammount")
    private int ammount;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Province province;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private City city;
    
    @Column(name="postal_code")
    private String postalCode;
    
    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "deal_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Deal deal;
```

Deal:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "deals")
@SuppressWarnings({"serial"})
public class Deal extends FullBaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "deals_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "deals_seq", 
                       name = "deals_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name = "deal_number")
    private String dealNumber;
    
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @NotNull
    private Client client;
    
    @Column(name = "closed")
    private Boolean closed;
```

As the title says, "quotas" show an array inside an array when I test it on postman, why?

response example from postman:

```json
[
    [
        {
            "createdAt": null,
            "updatedAt": null,
            "createdBy": null,
            "updatedBy": null,
            "id": 27,
            "state": {
             ........
        }
   ]
]
```

This method getAllQuota is invoked by a controller which exposes an endpoint, so I think it's not relevant to show.

I tried getting the first result, but It returns an Int so I discarded that option.
I think It's a model problem, but I can't see where It is.

Comment: Because that is what you ask for with `FROM Quota q, QuotaLine ql, Deal d`. Your query returns 3 objects per row. What you probably wanted was JOIN instead o including them in the FROM. Or add `SELECT q FROM Quota q...`.

Comment: Yes that's true, I saw in another stack overflow post how a guy explained that JOIN should be used like that with entity manager. Now I know It's possible to write it like:

""FROM Quota q INNER JOIN QuotaLine ql on (q.id = ql.quota.id)"

Answer (score 0):

It was a query problem. As [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) said, I was asking for 3 objects.

String baseQuery = "FROM Quota q, QuotaLine ql, Deal d " + "where ql.quota = q " + "and ql.deal = d ";

To solve it -> "FROM Quota q INNER JOIN QuotaLine ql on (q.id = ql.quota.id)"